# Swift and Salesforce IOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, salesforce, xcode6

I am trying to create a connected app with Salesforce IOS SDK and Swift and followed the steps mentioned  in the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Mt02DzsOBo but as try to attach the "Appname-Swift.h"file in the AppDelegate.m file I am getting an error.Please help what can be done next.

> 1)I have created the native connected app as per Salesforce IOS
>   Description
>    2)Created the bridge for Swift
>   "MySampleApp-Bridging-Header.h"
>   [image] 3)Added SFRestDelegate to RootVC.Swift
>   4)Imported the important header files to
>   "mySampleApp-bridging-Header.h" that is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SFRestAPI.h"
```

5)As soon I am trying to import #import "MySampleApp-Swift.h" I am getting the error
I am using OSX mavericks with XCode-6(4beta)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think in the video or in the [sample code repository](https://github.com/rajaraodv/Swifty/tree/master/Swifty/Classes) there is a file named `MySampleApp-Swift.h`

Comment: What I have done is I have changed the name of the app(that I can do I guess) to MySampleApp so the change.

Comment: You can change the app name alright. But did you really create a file 'MySampleApp-Swift.h'? The error is very explicit about missing this file. And based on your question, I thought you were going to create a MySampleApp-Bridging-Header.h

Comment: But as per the tutorial it will be an auto generated header file for swift that will do the job and it should be of order "Appname-Swift.h"(this will be auto generated).